# Equivalent definitions of unramified characters

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, definitions

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over a local field $F$. An unramified character of $G(F)$ is a continuous character $\chi: G(F)\to\mathbb{C}^\times$ that is trivial on all compact subgroups of $G(F)$.

It seems to be a well-known result that unramified characters are precisely those that are trivial on $G(F)^1=\bigcap_{X^*(G)_F}\ker|\chi|_F$, however I have been unable to find a proof of this in the literature. Is there a reference for this result?

The subgroup $G(F)^1$ contains all compact subgroups of $G(F)$. On page 8 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.09112.pdf it is stated that there is an unpublished proof by Abe, Henniart, Herzig, and Vigneras that, in the case that $F$ is non-archimedean, $G(F)^1$ is generated by the compact subgroups of $G(F)$. Is there a reference for this result? Is it true if $F$ is archimedean?